# HP Protein Folding Optimization

Tags: optimization, concurrency, parallel-processing, folding

I am messing around with this: http://www.cburch.com/ccsc-nifty/12/bur/handout.html (not for homework or anything like that, I'm just interested).

I am wondering how this can be optimized. The poster of that assignment claims there are lots of simple optimizations and a "dumb" parallel way to do it.

If I can write this concurrently, that would be optimal.

Also, I have heard of things like ant colony optimizations but haven't found a lot on implementation or application to this purpose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: As it stands your question is way too broad to be a good fit here on SO (so I've voted to close it because of that).  Mess around some more, get a few lines of code written, when you hit specific programming problems, bring them back and the community will help.

Comment: Well I have the thing implemented in Go, based off the link provided. The problem is that there's just too much calculation going on... it's a brute force program. I need to find ways to reduce the amount of different combinations of foldings I need to try.

Comment: Based on the reference implementation from the link I posted, how can it be implemented concurrently?